# I want a NumericUpDown to bind to a value and also contain a numeric string. How do I do that?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My NumericUpDown is bound to a double variable.  When displayed, I want it to show as "20/" plus whatever the decimal value is. I want the up/down arrows to be able to change the double that the control is bound to.

I tried this:

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Text="{Binding Path=DoubleValue}" FormatString=20/{}{0}/>
```

as well as several other similar things, but I keep getting **Format Exceptions**.  What's the proper format for FormatString?

I also tried using a converter with the following code:

```
public class DvaConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double dva = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        switch (System.Convert.ToInt16(parameter))
        {
            case 20:
                return string.Format("20/{0}", dva);
                break;
            case 6:
                return string.Format("6/{0}", dva);
                break;
            case 1:
                return string.Format("{0}", dva);
                break;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string dva = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dva))
        {
            dva = dva.Replace("20/", "").Replace("6/", "");
            return System.Convert.ToDouble(dva);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this for the XAML:

```
xctk:DecimalUpDown Text="{Binding Path=UncorrectedDvaSnellen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource DvaConverter}, ConverterParameter=20}"/>
```

Still got a FormatException.

Comment: You might be better off going through a converter.

Comment: I actually tried that, too.  Still got the FormatException.  I have a bad feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint inside the Convert / ConvertBack methods? If you debug your code, you get the point! Try to use try/catch block.

Comment: @IgorDamiani I have put breakpoints in the Convert / ConvertBack methods.  Convert does exactly what I want it to do and returns the string that I expect.  And then a FormatException is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of trial and error, the correct answer is apparently.

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding Path=DoubleValue}" FormatString="2\0/0"/>
```

I think I'd tried that FormatString, and I'd tried switching from binding to Text to binding to Value, but I hadn't tried them together.